# Output everything before the first slash '/' in a line

Tags: text-processing

I have a set of URLs and I'm really only interested in anything up to the first `/`.

How can I capture this info to a text file?

Input (`foo.txt`):

```
apple.com/nothing.js  
t1.msn.com/cookie=22  
happy.net/whatever
```

Output (redirected to file: `foo_filter.txt`):

```
apple.com/  
t1.msn.com/  
happy.net/
```

Comment: do you have URLs such as `unix.stackexchange.com`? and not something `unix.stackexchange.com/questions` for example. then what output you are expecting? skip those lines or print the URL?

Comment: and what about for URLs including `https://` like [`https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)?

Comment: @αғsнιη I don't think this is a duplicate. Here, the obvious pattern match is to be included in the result, which can be done trivially because it's a single character. In the other answer the obvious pattern match is to be excluded from the result. Not the same at all

Comment: @roaima these are same. there and also here OPs want to cut off upto specifc patterns (here up to first `/` string, there up to `.com` string) and in both they wanted that strings to be included in the result. so no doubt from me that these are exact duplicates.

Comment: @αғsнιη no, here [they want](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/734952/output-everything-before-the-first-slash-in-a-line?noredirect=1#comment1395232_734957) the split character, there they do not.

Comment: @roaima there also they wanted the split string too (which that is `.com`). please read the Q there slowly then you will find it. in addition you can compare your answer with answers there. both Q and A are duplicates except you have an extra cut approach which that answer even is not what OP wanted here but later approaches (printing the split character) is

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the trailing slash, it's very straightforward

```
cut -d/ -f1 foo.txt
awk -F/ '{print $1}' foo.txt
sed 's!/.*!!' foo.txt
```

If you do want that trailing slash, then

```
awk -F/ '{print $1 "/"}' foo.txt
sed 's!/.*!/!' foo.txt
```

All of these will write to *stdout* (your screen) so you can see the result immediately. To redirect them to your target file, use `>foo_filter.txt` on the end of the command. For example,

```
awk -F/ '{print $1 "/"}' foo.txt >foo_filter.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `Miller`:

```
mlr --nidx --ifs '/' -N cut -f 1 file
```

or using GNU `datamash`:

```
datamash dirname 1 <file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk 'sub("/.*","/")' foo.txt
apple.com/
t1.msn.com/
happy.net/
```

Answer (score 0):

Your better option here is actually `sed`, because it edits the stream on a line by line basis.

Try the following:

```
sed 's/\/.*//' foo.txt > foo_filter.txt
```

This tells `sed` that - per line - replace anything after the `/` with nothing.  You then redirect the output to the new file with the `>`. You can read more from the sed manual [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html).

Note: because `sed` is greedy, you might need to specify the first slash with a `1` at the end of the command:

```
sed 's/\/.*//1' foo.txt > foo_filter.txt
```

You definitely can use `awk` if you have strings with multiple slashes:

```
awk -F"/" '{print $1"/"}' foo.txt > foo_filter.txt
```

The `-F"/"`  sets the field delimiter to forward slash, and `'{print $1"/"}'` prints the first field followed by a slash (since it's the field delimiter, it gets removed on print and has to be re-included).

Comment: `print $1/` in awk would be a syntax error. Don't escape the `/` in your sed command, just pick a different delimiter like `:`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an `awk` and a `cut` solution.

```
$ cut -f1 -d/ foo.txt
apple.com
t1.msn.com
happy.net
$ awk -F/ '{ print $1 }' foo.txt
apple.com
t1.msn.com
happy.net
$ awk -F/ '{ print $1"/" }' foo.txt
apple.com/
t1.msn.com/
happy.net/
$
```

Answer (score 0):

##### With just [grep](/questions/tagged/grep):

```
$ grep -oE '^[^/]+/' foo.txt
```

##### Output:

```
apple.com/
t1.msn.com/
happy.net/
```

##### To fulfill all the requirements:

```
grep -oE '^[^/]+/' foo.txt | tee foo_filter.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, time to learn some switches, apparently!

Comment: Advice to newcomers: If an answer solves your problem, please accept it by clicking the large check mark (✓) next to it and optionally also up-vote it (up-voting requires at least 15 reputation points). If you found other answers helpful, please up-vote them. Accepting and up-voting helps future readers.